# using Jquery and AJAX in cakePHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, prototypejs

Is it posible to use the Jquery library and the AJAX libraries (prototype & aculo) together in CAKE-PHP?
is it going to cause compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, make sure that you'll use `no-conflict` object for jQuery or use `jQuery` instead of `$` while using jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible.
Assuming you have prototype.js included in head, 
you can add this to your template where you need jquery to work:

```
<?=$javascript->link('jquery-1.4.4.min'); ?>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     /* do something.. */
  }   

</script>
```